# Error Resolving Firebase Dependency in Android Studio: Execution Failed for Task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, visual-studio-code, gradle

I'm creating an app using Flutter in Visual Studio Code, and I'm using an emulator from Android Studio. However, today when I tried to run the code I had written, it gave me an error. Could anyone help me fix it?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :firebase_ml_vision

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 41s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

i have checked the vision of firebase and updated it but nothing happen, tried to update gradle on android studio